# Can I mention OP in my answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, feedback, reference

Is it useful to mention OP in my answer for attracting OP and getting his/her feedback fast? For example, I'm the first person to answer OP's question now I want to get OP's feedback fast by mentioning OP in comment section of my answer(`@OP Does it fix your problem?`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to use a comment to ping the asker of a question that you have answered because they will already be notified of it.

More information on how comment pings work can be found at [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

It is also wise to be aware of this Q&A to learn why pings are not available within questions and answers, and are restricted to only certain types of comments: [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

When someone answers my question they will know whether it fixes my problem, as soon as I do, by whether I click the Accept button.

I would advise patience over following up in the way you describe.

Comment: First thank you so much for your answer. I know how to ping the asker. I would like to know is it correct or not?

Comment: I would advise patience over following up in the way you describe.  If I already know that someone has answered my question then I would prefer not to feel pressured by a follow up ping from them effectively saying "have you decided whether my answer to you works for you yet?"

Comment: @alirezasafian in short: no, it's not "correct". For many people, it would seem on the verge of rude to keep pinging them.